# How to hide someparts in otherpage except home in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, codeigniter-hmvc

I want to show a slider module on home page but hide it on rest of the site. Could anyone help me hide it. I am using HMVC in Codeigniter

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-11 col-lg-11 navdiv" id="services_menu">

                        <?php
    echo Modules::run('slider');
    ?>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
<?php
if($this->router->fetch_class()=='home_controller_name'){
?>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-11 col-lg-11 navdiv" id="services_menu">
        <?php
            echo Modules::run('slider');
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php                       
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an seperate view for slider as slider.php. Put your following code into it

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-11 col-lg-11 navdiv" id="services_menu">

                    <?php
echo Modules::run('slider');
?>
                    </div>
```

And while loading the Home page, Load this slider.php also like as follows :

```
$this->load->view("header.php");
$this->load->view("slider.php");
$this->load->view("home.php", $data);
$this->load->view("footer.php");
```

For other pages don't load the view slider.php.

Cheers!!